# Django ORM distinct over annotated value

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a model which has a `DateTimeField` timestamp. What would be the best way to see the number of entries for each day (month, hours etc.) just by using Django ORM (not raw SQL)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the total rows with `Count`. For only years:

```
from django.db.models import Count


MyModel.objects.all().values("timestamp__year").annotate(
    count=Count("timestamp")
).order_by("timestamp__year")
```

For the same date:

```
MyModel.objects.all().values("timestamp__date").annotate(
    count=Count("timestamp")
).order_by("timestamp__date")
```

For the same hour:

```
MyModel.objects.all().values("timestamp__hour").annotate(
    count=Count("timestamp")
).order_by("timestamp__hour")
```

The last one obviously does not care about the day or year. But your description is very vague. In any case, this gives you a good overview.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
result_qs = MyModel.objects.all().annotate(
    date=TruncDay('created_at')
).values("date").annotate(
    created_count=Count('id')
).order_by("-date")

for instance in result_qs:
    instance.get('date')
    instance.get('created_count')
```